# Blogger: Implementing a simple IF with an OR in the condition

Tags: if-statement, blogger

In my blogger template I have the following code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
    <!-- A lot of lines of code -->
</b:if>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;archive&quot;'>
    <!-- The same lines of code -->
</b:if>
```

It is possible to merge both 'if's in a unique expresión?.  Something like using a simple logical OR?.  I've tried the following with no result:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot; ||
            data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot; &#124;&#124;
            data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot; OR
            data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot; || &quot;index&quot;'>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot; &#124;&#124; &quot;index&quot;'>
```

Note: &#124; is the HTML expression  for '|'.

I google it with no result, and I also reviewed [blogger b:if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032211/blogger-bif-statement/6910526#6910526), but I found no answer to this simple question.

----- edited -----

The desired result is having a code like:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;' || 
      cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;archive&quot;'>
    <!-- A lot of lines of code -->
</b:if>
```

In this way, I don't repeat the block 'lot of lines of code', resulting a more maintainable code, and simplier.

Anyway, knowing how to do a simple OR is a good thing to furure cases.

Comment: Why do u need OR. At a time only 1 page loads..so OR is perhaps useless....can u tell me final desired output so that we can look into it.

Comment: edited the question to answer you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simulate an OR operator in a blogger template, just use the IN operator.

In your case:

```xml
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;index&quot;,&quot;archive&quot;}'>
    <!-- This block is run only when the pageType is index or archive-->
</b:if>
```

Comment: I have tested it (using Blogger v2) and YES, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to accomplish this is transforming the OR to nested, negated ANDs.

In this case, 'data:blog.pageType' has only 4 valid values: item, static, index and archive.  So, the following code do the trick:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static&quot;'>

        <!-- This block is run only when the pageType is archive or index -->
        <!-- A lot of lines of code -->

    </b:if>
</b:if>
```

**Edit:** This works fine, but maybe you'll want to try the accepted answer given by Marcos.